# Need to show height of the Div as same in every browser

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I have a `div` on my page, and the content of the `div` is generated dynamically through javascript with an accurate CSS file. The `div` was displaying as I expected and works fine. 
My problem is when I am checking the height of the `div` i shows differently in different browsers but I really need to find the height of the div for some other operations.

I tried these things but failed:

1. removing the `px` and applying `%`.
2. Used ResetCSS
3. Used NormalisedCSS

Please see this fiddle I've created: http://jsfiddle.net/mouli_13579/FxK9F/5

Comment: Hi i added the css file in jsfiddle
but i cant able to add the link here
http://jsfiddle.net/mouli_13579/FxK9F/5/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Alien
Even with styles or without styles it was showing different heights only

Comment: hi if you want to have a fix height in all browser did you try to give fix height like example `.wrapper {height:400px;}`

Answer (score 0):

dont define height if your content are displaying dynamically
or better you use

```
 html, body {height:100%}
 .yourclass { height:100%}
```

hope this will help

Comment: Thanks @Azad
i kept height to 100% for both body and my div but its not showing the same height in different browsers.
Thanks In Advance,
Krishna.